# Edittext content and checkbox checked change after scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView that any row have a Checkbox and Edittext. I make a simple adapter and use it for inflate my xml. but **after scrolling** in listview  (if list bigger then one page),the **contents of Edittexts** and **Check mark of Checkboxes** **change**. my adapter is in below .help me friends.

```
package com.moghaddasan.adinemarket;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BuyProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    BuyProductAdapter adapter;

    public BuyProductAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mDetailEditText = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.buy_prd_counter);
            holder.delChk = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.delCheck); 
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        return vi;
    } 

    static class ViewHolder{
        public EditText mDetailEditText;
        public CheckBox delChk;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `ListView` your rows will get recycled (reused) as soon as you start scrolling. In order to keep the *state* (Checkbox checked, EditText input) of your different rows you have to save and reapply them in your `getView(...)` method.

#### Basic idea for the checkBox

```
int mCheckBoxState[];

public BuyProductAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    // ...
    mCheckBoxState = new int[d.size];
}

// ...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...

    if(mCheckBoxState[position] == 0)
       holder.delChk.setChecked(false);
    else
       holder.delChk.setChecked(true);

    holder.delChk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (compoundButton == holder.delChk) {
            if (b) {
                mCheckBoxState[position] = 1;
            } else {
                mCheckBoxState[position] = 0;
            }
        }
      }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work or i cant use it correctly, can you give me full code of it? and what must do fo edittexts?

Comment: Well for EditText you simply create a String-Array and save the input to this. You may need to add a `TextWatcher` in order to know when something is entered by the user.